# integrate ZKSforce with Salesforce Sdk API

Tags: ios, salesforce

Is this possible to custom login after passing username and password with ZKSForce and for having account list for ex- by salesforce sdk api

Comment: can you be clearer on what you're trying to do, ZKSforce & the Salesforce SDK are both libraries for calling the salesforce Web services APIs, why would you need both?

Comment: i need to implement custom login in which i can pass username and password through my view not in webview in salesforce sdk
but i found the way in ZKSforce for custom login

Comment: @superfell please suggest something i found the same question on stackoverflow but i am unable to get the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can call loginwithUsername:password method in FDCServerSwitchboard provided by zksforce

```
[[FDCServerSwitchboard switchboard] loginWithUsername:usernameTextField.text password:passwordTextField.text target:rootViewController selector:@selector(loginResult:error:)];
```

You can refer the [loginviewcontroller](https://github.com/palaniraja/Force.com-Toolkit-for-iOS/blob/master/SVNTest/LoginViewController.m) provided in zksforce sample code

I have also blogged with snippets required to do regular works with zksforce api @ [my blog - Developing iOS application for salesforce [How to]](http://dr-palaniraja.blogspot.in/2012/01/developing-ios-application-for.html)